# Dropdown Menu Slow Response and Disappearing on Hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I'm having issues with my dropdown navigation for just this page. The response times on the navigation are extremely slow, and the dropdown menu will show momentarily on hover, but quickly disappears. I'm unsure if it has to do with the main element below, or not. If you have any insight or help, it would be great. I'm a graphic major, not web, so this isn't my forte.

```css
body{
 background-color: white;
}


#page-wrapper{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: auto;
 background-image: url(Images/brick-wall-2209991.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

li {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.span01,.span02,.span03,.span04,.span05,.span06,.span07,.span08,.span09,.span10,.span11,.span12 
{
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.first-child{
 margin-left: 0;
}

.last-child{
 margin-right: 0;
}

.span01 {
 width: 60px;
}

.span02 {
 width: 140px;
}

.span03 {
width: 220px;
}

.span04 {
width: 300px;
}

.span05 {
width: 380px;
}

.span06 {
width: 460px;
}

.span07 {
width: 540px;
}

.span08 {
width: 620px;
}

.span09 {
width: 700px;
}

.span10 {
width: 780px;
}

.span11 {
width: 860px;
}

.span12 {
width: 940px;
}

.reset{
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden; 
 width: 0px;
}



.header {height: 115px;
   background-color: #1e241b;
  width: 960px;
}

/********Navigation********/

ul { margin-right: 20px;}

li {text-align: center;
 display: inline;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14pt;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 color: #d98a79;
 
    }
li a:link {color: #d98a79;}

li a:visited {
    color: #d98a79;
}

li a:hover {
 text-decoration-color: white;
 color: white;
 
}

li a:active {
    color: white;
} 

nav {text-align: center;
 padding-left: 110px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 70px;
 }
nav ul ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}

nav ul ul li {
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
}

nav ul ul li a {
 padding-top: 15px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 text-align: left;
 
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
 display: block;
}

nav ul {
 background-color: #1e241b;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after {
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}

nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

nav ul li a{
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 8px;
 
}
.bar {height: 190px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 text-align: right;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 font-size: 90pt;
 position: relative;
 top:-140px;
 left: -40px;
 margin-bottom: -140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sous Vide - About</title>
<link href="secondary.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed');
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-wrapper">
 
 <header class="span12 header first-child last-child">
  
  <nav class="span12">
  
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menus</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Seasonal Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Breakfast Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lunch Menu</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
   
  </nav>
     </header>
<div class="reset"></div> 
 
 <main class="bar span12"></main>
  <h1>About Us</h1>
 
<div class="reset"></div>
```

Comment: delete the "About Us" h1 and that will stop happening. Use Chrome debugger you'll see that that element over laps your menu.

Comment: The H1 tag necessary for the assignment I'm working on. It's required in the rubric. Is there a way to rearrange it to stop it from happening?

Comment: Sure, I was just showing you that it's that element causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the h1 element to a div container and style it with CSS.

**Example:**

```
<div id="DIVNAME">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
</div>
```

in css:

```
#DIVNAME { height: 100px; width 100px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**hi try this: it will work**

```
h1{
clear:both;
}
```